# Resolving CSS namespaces in HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a web-dev newbie and I'm working on a webapp which displays html from other sources. 
The main webapp is based on bootstrap and the other external html is embedded in a bootstrap modal. I want the modal content to look exactly like they would if they were a separate html page.  Since the embedded html can contain elements that have been bootstrap stylized, any td, tr or table contained within the external html are stylized as well.

Is there a way to tell html something like "Within this div, don't use bootstrap styles?"

As an aside, since this is an internal framework and will be used by a few people, I'm not worried about xss exploits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I interpreted your question correctly. But I understand you want to make a div (or whatever element) *not* have bootstrap styles. You can then, override those styles using your own CSS stylesheet, applying new styles to that element along with the [`!important` rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to prefix all bootstrap clases with something like .bt so the declarations ends up like:

```
.bt table
.bt input
.bt td
```

then to the main div (or body) of the site using bootstrap, add the bt class like `<div class="bt">`